# Detect if none of the EditTexts has focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have a few EditTexts in my activity. The problem is simple: If none of them has focus, I will show a button. If any of them has focus, I will hide the button.

Here's what I did:

```
    usernameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            usernameFocus = hasFocus;
            adjustVisibility();
        }
    });

    passwordEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            passwordFocus = hasFocus;
            adjustVisibility();
        }
    });

    private void adjustVisibility() {
        if(usernameFocus || passwordFocus) {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

**The problem:**
When I change focus from one EditText to the other, the button gets momentarily visible between the focus change. I want to eliminate that. Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Further elaboration of the problem when a user clicks on the password field after filling up the username field:

**BUTTON INVISIBLE**

1. Username Field has focus
2. `onFocusChange()` of Username field gets called
3. Username Field loses focus

**BUTTON IS VISIBLE**

4. `onFocusChange()` of password field gets called
5. password field gets focus.

**BUTTON INVISIBLE**

Clearly, between points 3 and 4, neither username field nor password field has focus. In that small fraction of time, the button becomes visible, which is what I'm trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some delay if you don't want to display between switching from one edittext to other

```
  private void adjustVisibility() {
    if (usernameFocus || passwordFocus) {
        mButtonVisible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                if (usernameFocus || passwordFocus) {
                    mButtonVisible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    mButtonVisible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists because between the focus change, this `adjustVisibility()` method gets called twice. Delaying it only keeps the momentarily blink of the button to a prolonged blink. The button now shows up for about 5 seconds :|

Comment: @Akeshwar This is working for me. when you change focus from one to other edittext last value of Boolean  variable is true so your button get hide. now if your focus loses than both are false so button display to the end user

Comment: When I switch from one EditText to the other, the method `adjustVisibility()` gets called twice successively, right? In the first call, both values are false. Therefore, the button shows up. But the second call follows quickly in which one of the values is true. Therefore the button disappears. So, in between this transition, the button did show up once. And that's where my problem lies.

Comment: @Akeshwar right it called twice but when first time it called and all boolean are false it is not distractedly show your button it wait for 5 second if you don't get focus on other edittext button will display else current value of boolean is changed so it will not display button, if 5seconds are less please increase   delay time

Comment: It should work that way, but it is not. Here's the screen-video I've recording with the emulator and the logs using the delay of 5000 ms: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2qoAuLeYjaY096aDB6UzBnVWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As you can see, there's almost no delay-time between the two calls of the method. Moreover, I cannot use the delay to be more than 100-150 ms because when I start the activity for the first time, and click on one of the fields to gain focus, it will take that amount of time (5000 ms) to vanish the button, whereas, I want it instantaneous. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if(parentView.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText)
{
   //Hide Buttom
}else{
   // Show Button
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. A quick question: Where do I place it?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling adjust visibility in focus change listener just check if the other edit text does not have focus like below.

```
 usernameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        usernameFocus = hasFocus;
        if(!passwordEditText.hasFocus())
        adjustVisibility();
    }
});

passwordEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        passwordFocus = hasFocus;
        if(!usernameEditText.hasFocus())
        adjustVisibility();
    }
});
```

See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't solve the problem. Let's talk about this block: `if(!passwordEditText.hasFocus())
        adjustVisibility();` in the focus change listener of the usernameEditText. Clearly, `!passwordEditText.hasFocus()` will always return true when I switch between the two EditTexts. I've made the question more clear, please checkout.